# Understand callback function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have doubt in this stack code:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onblur="select()">Month<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="month">
            <li><a href="#01">January</a></li>
            <li><a href="#02">February/a></li>
            <li><a href="#03">March</a></li>
            <li><a href="#04">April</a></li>
            <li><a href="#05">May</a></li>
            <li><a href="#06">Juny</a></li>
            <li><a href="#07">July</a></li>
            <li><a href="#08">August</a></li>
            <li><a href="#09">September</a></li>
            <li><a href="#10">October</a></li>
            <li><a href="#11">November</a></li>
            <li><a href="#12">December</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<script>
    function select(){
        var value;

        $(document).on('click', 'li a', function () {
             value = $(this).attr('href');
             console.log(value); // Result is the value set. Ex: Value = Link
        });    

        console.log(value); // Result is undefined
     }
</script>
```

**In this stretch** the function is called when button is clicked. Tha value of the variable `value` don't remains outside the JQuery function:

```
function select(){
    var value;

    $(document).on('click', 'li a', function () {
        value = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(value); // Result is the value set. Ex: Value = Link
    });    

    console.log(value); // Result is undefined
}
```

How to use variable outside the Jquery Function and why Jquery it has this behavior?

Comment: How you call the function ?

Comment: Using `onblur` event of button (Twitter Bootstrap).

Comment: if you call `select()` it will just bind a click event in any tag `a` inside `li`..

Comment: have you tried `function select() { console.log($(this).attr("href")); }` ?

Comment: @Daniel Almeida I tried now, result is `undefined`.

Comment: are you using `onblur` in which element? `a`, `button`, `input` ....

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Try the steps I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You cannot get the expected output for the given script. Also there is no fault in Jquery or Javascript.

Before explaining the code flow, I would like to mention, the event-handler registration is not correct.

**Explanation:**

Every time the onblur event occurs (mean click on month button and click outside) the select function will be called and following 3 actions will be performed.

```
function select() {
    //(1)value variable decalred and it is "undefined"
    var value;

    //(2)event handler registration happens
    $(document).on('click', 'li a', function () {
        //this block will not executed during select function call
        value = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(value); // Result is the value set. Ex: Value = Link
    });    

    //(3)prints value variable and it is undefined, regardless of how many times
    //   select function is called.
    console.log(value); // Result is undefined
}
```

By looking at the above flow, only inner block have value of "value" variable. If you call select function to check it back, since select function has the value declaration, it will be declared again with "undefined" and **it register event handlers again which is bad** and prints the new instance's "value" variable i.e. "undefined".

Okay, lets try keeping variable "value" outside of the select function

```
var value; // <-- declaring outside select function
function select() {

    $(document).on('click', 'li a', function () {
        value = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(value); // Result is the value set. Ex: Value = Link
    });    
    console.log(value); // Result is undefined
}
```

Check the above changes in this http://jsfiddle.net/gLeoyuLh/1/

Now you can access "value" variable outside the function also. But it still has "multiple event handler registration issue" and also keeping "value" outside the function (globally) is not a problem/error, but you should avoid it. Its not a good practice.

**Solution**

Declare the event-registers during onload or there are many other ways you can do it. Check this onload changes for the same example http://jsfiddle.net/gLeoyuLh/2/

Comment: thanks for the explication and the suggestion of the book =]. But isn't the solution in my case. My problem is the variable don't be set out of the context `$("#month").find("a").on('click', function () { }` -  the value of the variable `value` continue `undefined`.

Comment: @LucasCosta I re-wrote the whole answer. Hope it gives more clarification.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explication @rajuGT, I undestand how works the events in JQuery and Javascript and I'm consulting more materials for learn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but your variables are out of scope.

```
var value;

$(document).on('click', 'li a', function () {
    value = $(this).attr('href');
});    

function getValue(){
   return value;
}
```

After clicking the link, you can call this to retrieve the value:

```
getValue()
```

Comment: Thansk @Jasper, but the result in the same, when I call `getValue()` and show in console, the output is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just bind `click` the to the `a` without the `onblur` event? [Example..](http://goo.gl/jdiR1c)

```
<script>
    $("#month").find("a").on('click', function () {
        value = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(value); // Result is the value set. Ex: Value = Link
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I try your suggestion but out of the context `$("#month").find("a").on('click', function () { }` the value of the variable `value` continue `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

The thing in here is that the 'value' value is gonna be assigned when a 'li a' is clicked.

Right now your function is just doing the following:

```
function select(){
 var value;
 console.log(value);
}
```

In the rest of your code you are just adding a click listener that is gonna be called when a user execute a click event.

I think you have to write something like that:

```
function select(){


    $(document).on('click', 'li a', function () {
console.log(value); // Result is the value set. Ex: Value = Link
      changeValue($(this).attr('href'));

    });    


}

function changeValue(val){

//Create some code to change the value of a global attribute or the desired behavior

}
```